# bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: 14.04, vps

My server is currently down. Apparently he has no room.
How do I solve this?

```
    danilodorgam@ny3-vps:/etc$ df
    Filesystem                1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
    udev                         504600        4    504596   1% /dev
    tmpfs                        101788      336    101452   1% /run
    /dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT  30830588 12305880  16935572  43% /
    none                              4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    none                           5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
    none                         508924        0    508924   0% /run/shm
```

...

```
 df -ih
Filesystem                Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                        124K   402  123K    1% /dev
tmpfs                       125K   312  124K    1% /run
/dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT   1.9M  1.9M     0  100% /
none                        125K     2  125K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        125K     1  125K    1% /run/lock
none                        125K     1  125K    1% /run/shm
none                        125K     2  125K    1% /run/user
```

Comment: please add the output of `df -ih` to your question

Comment: @CharlesGreen I added the result.

Comment: This is indicating that the inodes of your file system are consumed - possibly lots and lots of very small files somewhere?  There are several references on askubuntu to no inodes remaining:  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/668582/false-disk-full-error-apt-get-unable-to-install-or-remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668582/false-disk-full-error-apt-get-unable-to-install-or-remove)

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/713843/utility-says-theres-no-more-free-disk-space-when-theres-plenty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713843/utility-says-theres-no-more-free-disk-space-when-theres-plenty)  and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/301466/files-are-piling-up-in-usr-src-how-can-i-stop-this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301466/files-are-piling-up-in-usr-src-how-can-i-stop-this)

Comment: @DavidFoerster That looks like a good solution - a nicer single line command for finding the files might be `sudo du -a -d 1 --inodes . | sort -nr | head -20`

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Don't tell me, tell OP – preferably with a proper answer! ;-]