# Says i'm out of storage but i'm not

Tags: server, 18.04, hard-drive, storage, inode

When I try and run any app or tab auto complete it says I'm out of space ex. `-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`

But when I run `df -h` it says I have 67% space used

```bash
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           1.6G  1.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/minecraft--vg-root   48G   31G   15G  67% /
tmpfs                           7.9G   20K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19457
/dev/loop1                       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/certbot/3024
/dev/loop2                       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/sda1                       719M  139M  544M  21% /boot
tmpfs                           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Here is `df -ih`

```bash
Filesystem                     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                             2.0M   441  2.0M    1% /dev
tmpfs                            2.0M   727  2.0M    1% /run
/dev/mapper/minecraft--vg-root   3.1M  3.1M     0  100% /
tmpfs                            2.0M     3  2.0M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            2.0M     4  2.0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                            2.0M    18  2.0M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                        658   658     0  100% /snap/snapd/19457
/dev/loop1                       7.5K  7.5K     0  100% /snap/certbot/3024
/dev/loop2                        12K   12K     0  100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/sda1                         46K   313   46K    1% /boot
tmpfs                            2.0M    12  2.0M    1% /run/user/1000
```

Any help would be help full

Comment: Did you also check the inode usage - as suggested here for example [bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948722/bash-cannot-create-temp-file-for-here-document-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the post to include the inode stuff

Comment: You've run out of inodes - meaning you have too many files on the disk.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes. So you are out of storage - just not space, but rather "reference points" (inodes).

Comment: thank you both for helping me find the problem

Comment: I've added an answer to the duplicate post, explaining how to reformat your filesystem with more inodes. https://askubuntu.com/a/1478154/1066942

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: When you create the file-system (*format* time) you give details and set size limits. Defaults work for most circumstances assuming sufficient maintenance is done on the system, but defaults won't work for all situations.